# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, php error

Tags: php

I am getting this error accessing my site. I have used the same files for three different servers, including my local server and it's running fine. Can someone shed some lights?

```
    $stringIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$intIp = ip2long($stringIp);


$inDB = @mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM av_whoIsOnline WHERE ip=".$intIp);

if(!mysql_num_rows($inDB)) //CODE IN QUESTION <---------
{


if($_COOKIE['geoData'])
{

list($city,$countryName,$countryAbbrev) =     explode('|',mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_COOKIE['geoData'])));
}
else
{


$xml = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/?ip='.$stringIp);

$city = get_tag('gml:name',$xml);
$city = $city[1];

$countryName = get_tag('countryName',$xml);
$countryName = $countryName[0];

$countryAbbrev = get_tag('countryAbbrev',$xml);
$countryAbbrev = $countryAbbrev[0];


setcookie('geoData',$city.'|'.$countryName.'|'.$countryAbbrev, time()+60*60*24*30,'/');
}

$countryName = str_replace('(Unknown Country?)','UNKNOWN',$countryName);

if (!$countryName)
{
$countryName='UNKNOWN';
$countryAbbrev='XX';
$city='(Unknown City?)';
}
```

Comment: mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')?

Comment: Remove the @ symbol and re-run the script. You're most likely getting an error trying to access your database.

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM` ? Why would someone give such names?

Comment: And in which line is the error reported?

Comment: Where's the database connection by the way

Answer (score 0):

Take out the @ sign before `@mysql_query`. This obviously suppresses errors. If you do get an error, `$inDB` will not be a valid resource, so you will get the error you are getting. Your problem is most likely in the line before.

Also note that the `mysql` library has been deprecated in favour of `mysqli` and `PDO`. Consider changing your code to use one of the newer libraries since they are safer

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. Thanks for the replies.

This was an online script I grabbed from the net awhile back. I've changed host using the same script and got this error. After I uploaded the db, I've deleted any entries in 'av_whoIsOnline'. Then the error occurred. Inserted back the entries and error is gone.

My db connection is located in another file.